# Date Time convertion in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, date, format

I have a string coming from Data base in this format:

```
  string DateNonFormat =  "Feb 24, 1998";
```

Now I want to convert the format of this string to 1998,Feb 24 
I tried this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateNonFormat, "yyyy mm dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it gives Error of String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
So I tried to convert the string into date but it converted the whole string into numeric date.`2/24/1998`

How can I take the `Feb 24, 1998` to `1998,Feb 24` without converting it into Numeric date?

Comment: The format you provide to `ParseExact` has to match the format in the string you're parsing.  It's not clear what you mean by "numeric date" to be honest. A value of "1998,Feb 24" looks very odd to me, and definitely *isn't* yyyy/MM/dd...

Comment: You'd have to parse the string. Just use a custom `.ToString()` format after converting it (which it looks like you're able to do): `date.ToString("yyyy,MMM dd")`

Comment: It doesn't look like you're targeting a legitimate DateTime format. I find this link very useful:  http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact(DateNonFormat, "MMM dd, yyyy").ToString("yyyy,MMM dd");` ?

Comment: Should be  DateTime date =  DateTime.ParseExact(DateNonFormat, "MMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  Once you get the DateTime object you can use ToString() to format results.  The format for months is always Capital letter (minutes are small letters) and you need 3M's to get the abbreviated Months.

Comment: @JonSkeet As I showed in the Code what I meant by numeric date was `2/24/1998` This was the numeric date and the actual string coming from data base had text for month in it.

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc Thanks for the Link it was really helpful

Comment: So you *don't* want the string in the format "yyyy/MM/dd" after all? Your question is *really* unclear. Are you saying you want to keep numeric months if the input has numeric months, but textual months if the input has textual months? That's a very odd requirement if so.

Comment: Why do you store your date as a string in the database in the first place?

Comment: @ckuri Database has all ready been structured I am just developing the process to use these dates and display differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahmad,
this should do the trick for you:

```
var DateNonFormat = @"Feb 24, 1998";
var newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateNonFormat, "MMM dd, yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy,MMM dd");
Console.WriteLine(newDate);
```

Comment: Glad to hear it Ahmad! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: Note that this code does not answer the question as asked since it first converts value to "numerical date" (DateTime)...

Answer (score 2):

You Should Try

```
 string res = "Feb 24, 1998";
        DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(res, "MMM dd, yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      Output.Text=(d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: This kind of worked but the code from @Jim was much clear Thanks for your time :)